# log in using cellphones in asp.net Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, login-control

I have an ASP.NET application done in C#. When a user logs in using a phone it redirects the user to the mobile version of the application. Now what i need, is to find out what type of phone they use when they log in, Android , Iphone , etc... 
I'd appreciate any solution.

Comment: Please update your question: title asks about logging in, while post asks about browser detection (which probably should be dup of many other questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can glean quite a lot of information from `navigator.userAgent`

example:

```
function isAndroid()
{
    navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
}
```

This will return true if the device is Android.

More information here:

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer - not a web dev)
You are going to have to make a best guess by what type of browser they are using.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b(v=vs.100).aspx

You may be able to determine the OS and device based on this, depending on how the browser is versioned. It will require a xref table to map the browser to a device.

Also, check out this, I think it may help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET

HTH,
Eric